may as well vs. might as well

She may as well ask a question.


You might as well ask a question.

Is there any difference between them?

Although some distinction between the two constructions may be found, English speakers mix them up all the time without giving a thought to any implied difference of meaning.

A possibility with may is not as forceful as with might.

@Lambie I remember hearing that 'might' has more carefulness than 'may' so in the past I thought 'might' might have weaker meaning than 'may', but it's totally opposite now.

[careful, not carefulness]. No, there is no past tense here at all. These are spoken in the present time. might is not might have asked

You mean may as well+v and might as well+v has no tense? The same present tense in the examples : she may as well ask a question and she might as well as a question ?

They are present tense. The difference between may and might is one of degree.

They are interchangeable.
Cambridge Dictionary says we can use them to say what we think is 'the most logical course of action' and that 'might as well is more common than may as well'.
The usage frequency comparison
is consistent with what
Ngram shows.
